# Problem using read command within while read loop

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, variable, read

I am trying to set a while read loop line to read an input text file line by line and pass two strings as variables on each line in the text file.

```
    while IFS= read -r line
do
    # Read and pass two path strings as variables.
    read path1 path2
    echo "$path1"
    echo "$path2"
done < "$1"
```

It seems to process the next line in the text file at `read path1 path2` before it assigns variables for strings in each current line.

How can I pass strings as variables on each line before going to the next line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second `read` inside the body of the loop is incorrect here. It actually goes one line ahead than your first `read` call as part of the while loop. So for your requirement just read those variables as part of the first `read`

```
while read -r path1 path2; do
    echo "$path1"
    echo "$path2"
done < "$1"
```

As you see here, setting `IFS=` is also incorrect, when reading two variables because, resetting the field separator just picks up the line as a whole. By having its default value (white-space characters of space, tab, and newline) reading two variables will store the values from each line in a space separated list. This way we could have n-column delimited line and use n variables to read.

Now the values are available in those variables which you could pass to other commands as needed.

Let see how this works for a sample input file

```
foo bar
foo1 bar1
foo2 bar2
```

Running the first script in debug mode with `-x` set

```
$ bash -x script.sh
+ read -r path1 path2
+ echo 1
1
+ echo 2
2
+ read -r path1 path2
+ echo 3
3
+ echo 4
4
+ read -r path1 path2
+ echo abc
abc
+ echo def
def
+ read -r path1 path2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the line intact **and** extract values from it, you can use a [here-string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    read -r path1 path1 <<< "$line"
    echo "$line"
    echo "$path1:$path2"
done < file
```

---

Indeed, not all shells support here-strings. However, all POSIX-type shells support here documents.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    read -r path1 path1 << _LINE_
$line
_LINE_
    echo "$line"
    echo "$path1:$path2"
done < file
```

Comment: If the shell in question supports here-strings...

Answer (score 0):

With the redirection of the file into the `for` loop, all reading from standard input in the whole loop will read from the same file.  This means that the two `read` commands in the loop will read alternate lines from whatever file you pass as the first argument to your script.

It's a bit unclear to me where you want the data for `path1` and `path2` to come from.  If these are to be read from the file, simply do that in the loop head:

```
while read -r path1 path2; do
    printf 'path1 = "%s"\n' "$path1"
    printf 'path2 = "%s"\n' "$path2"
done <"somefile"
```

---

The rest of this answer assumes that you want to read something from the file, and then, in the loop, from the terminal.

To make the `read` in the loop body read from the terminal:

```
exec 3<"somefile"

while IFS= read -r words <&3; do
   read -r word1 word2 junk
   printf 'Got words = "%s"\n' "$words"
   printf 'Got word1 = "%s"\n' "$word1"
   printf 'Got word2 = "%s"\n' "$word2"
done
```

This makes the input to the first `read` come from the file `somefile` while the standard input stream of the second `read` will read from the terminal (or wherever the standard input stream of the script comes from).