# openmpi and read file in lines

Tags: linux, bash

I need to run several tasks in sequence. The task names are listed in a file (jobs.txt). I use the following code (example):

```
#! /bin/bash

while IFS=$'\r' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo $line
done < "jobs.txt"
```

It works well. However, I need to run these tasks with openmpi (in this example, change "echo $line" to "mpirun -n 4 echo $line"), then the script does not work any more... It only read the first line from "jobs.txt" and stopped.

Any idea what's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: I *suspect* it's because the first `mpirun` process "eats" the standard input that you are trying to read in the loop - similar to what happens here: [Problem using read command within while read loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423160/problem-using-read-command-within-while-read-loop). You may be able to prevent that by using a different file descriptor for the loop e.g. `read -u3 -r line ... 3< jobs.txt` but I don't know enough about OpenMPI to say whether that's the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes by assigning file descriptor other than stdin problem solved.